# Moving an Existential quantifier out of an implication using fitch.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I've looked just about every place I could think of and found the necessary rules multiple times, yet no proofs for those derived rules. Most proofs are for conjunctions, yet i have not found any for implications.

An example for such a statement and the corresponding target statement would be:

$\exists xPx\to\exists yPy\therefore\exists y(\exists xPx\to Py)$

I have made multiple attempts with $\to$I and $\neg$E but no luck so far. Can you guys give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis is a tautology, and thus is of no use in the proof.

From http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but I am not familiar with the LEM-Rule. Give me a second to look it up and I'll go ahead and mark the question as solved.

Comment: @Gidelix It's the Law of the Excluded Middle.  It's $\vee E$ except starting from an unstated assumption of $\exists x Px \vee \neg \exists x Px$.

Comment: Thank you! Marked as accepted answer, have a nice evening!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof done in Fitch:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The proof using $\vee$E from above works, but your proof doesn't use a tautology which is really handy when proving with no derived rules ^^!

Comment: @Gidelix You're welcome! :)